# Does Banner's strength affect the Hulk's?

Tags: marvel, the-incredible-hulk

While the magnitude depends on writer, the Hulk's strength is generally believed to increase with his rage. However, if Banner should decide to increase his strength, would this have an effect on the Hulk's baseline strength?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Probably not. The Hulk's physical power has little to do with the physical strength of Bruce Banner, and more to do with the manifestation of his psychological dysfunction of anger and rage. It is rage which powers the Hulk, so the angrier Banner is, the more powerful the Hulk's will be physically.**

Since Banner's physical strength is so minuscule in comparison to the Hulk, it is unlikely improving Banner's physical strength would do anything to augment the Hulk's already almost limitless reservoirs of physical strength.

> The Hulk possesses the potential for limitless physical strength depending directly on his emotional state, particularly his anger. This has been reflected in the repeated comment, "The madder Hulk gets, the stronger Hulk gets." After probing, the entity Beyonder once claimed that the Hulk's potential strength had "no finite element inside."
>
> Hulk's strength has been depicted as sometimes limited by Banner's subconscious influence; when Jean Grey psionically "shut Banner off", Hulk became strong enough to to overpower and destroy the physical form of the villain Onslaught.
>
> Writer Greg Pak described the Worldbreaker Hulk shown during World War Hulk as having a level of physical power where "Hulk was stronger than any mortal—and most immortals—who ever walked the Earth."
>
> His durability, regeneration, and endurance also increase in proportion to his temper. Hulk is resistant to injury or damage, though the degree to which varies between interpretations, but he has withstood the equivalent of solar temperatures, nuclear explosions, and planet-shattering impacts. - **[Hulk > Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk_%28comics%29#Powers_and_abilities)**

Comment: We know that the Hulk has no upper limit on his strength, but he needs to start somewhere when he transforms. Would any muscle-building that Banner does increase the amount of strength that the Hulk starts with?

Comment: Probably not. The reason is as soon as Banner transforms he is a 100+ ton monstrosity. He is already stronger than 95% of all of the heroes on Marvel Earth. With just the tiniest bit of anger, he becomes stronger than 99% of all the heroes on Marvel Earth. Banner's base contribution simply doesn't add enough to the equation to make it worth the effort. He would be at the same power level if Banner was a 98 pound weakling or a 250 pound titan. The Hulk simply makes his Banner form irrelevant in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that if banner were to increase his strength that the hulk's baseline strength would in fact increase as she-hulk discovered that if she trained in her human form that her hulk form became stronger as well.

Comment: She-Hulk's power/transformation is different from the Hulk's though.  Her transformations are triggered by fear, or she can conciously transform, whereas Bruce Banner's are involuntary and triggered/powered by rage/anger.

Answer (score 0):

The Hulk is physical manifestation of pure rage, the status of Banners body is irrelevant. Case in point, when wolverine stabbed Banner in the Ultimate serious the injury did not carry over.